# RunCode does not Run a Public Function in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to MS Access and I am trying to create a simple Macro with a call to VBA code.
the VBA code here is a sample (which also doesn't run)

```
Public Function RunImport()
Dim N As Integer
Dim Message1, Message2, Title, Default1, Default2, JulianSD, JulianED

Message1 = "Enter Julian Start Date"
Message2 = "Enter Julian End Date"
Title = "User Input Section"
Default1 = "17365"
Default2 = "17000"

JulianSD = InputBox(Message1, Title, Default1)
JulianED = InputBox(Message2, Title, Default2)
End Function
```

[image]

do you think you might be able to locate an issue here?
Thanks!

PS. I am using Version 14.0.7177.500 (32-bit). it wasn't my choice.. (if it were, I wouldn't be using access.. :p)

Comment: Did you place the function in a general module or behind the same object the macro is used in? Both work for me. Why use a macro?

Comment: I'm running `Version 14.0.7177.5000 (32-bit)` and it works for me. (I'm not sure whether there is any difference between `.500` and `.5000`.)

Comment: Are you sure it's the function that is bad?  Maybe it's the SetWarnings you are launching before it.  Also... another good habit is to declare all the variable types in your Dim statements.  Use "Option Explicit" before your public function to help remind you to write your Dim's out in full.

Comment: "Option Explicit" forces variable to be in Dim statement but  won't force declaring the datatype. If the datatype is not specified, VBA will default to variant.

Comment: Also note that "You can't call a Function procedure from a macro if the function name is the same as the module name."

Comment: @June7, Thank you for your detailed questions.
I am using the Julian SD and ED to import then append ranges of files, 
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ACRJ075 Import", "075", "P:\Shared\Directory\ASDF" & N & ".txt" where N ranges from SD to ED.
the Function does work in VBA mode without any problems, so that basically tells me that the Code is fine.
Code is located within the DB's module.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why you are using a macro to call VBA instead of another VBA procedure.

Comment: @June7 I guess you are right.. I have about 5 macros currently, each performing about 5 or so Queries to generate altimate output, the previous person who made this was not a developer and thought that Macros are easy to view and handle things instead of VBA.
if it give me any more trouble than just today's research, i might just move everything over to VBA.

Comment: Performing what kind of queries? INSERTs and UPDATEs? Yes, macros can be easier way to code for novice but if already building VBA, why mix in macros? I recommend you convert to VBA without further ado, regardless of the outcome of today's research.

Comment: Thank you @June7. moving everything to VBA should be simpler, and easier way to handle it. However, it still doesn't explain why a function will not run from a Macro.
there is built in RunCode command for it.
the thing is, I have few non-VBA friendly coworkers using this Access DB, and they would be utterly scared to do anything within VBA :p

Comment: If consideration of VBA-phobic coworkers is issue then why use any VBA? I think explanation of why your macro fails may be found in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177365(v=office.12).aspx. I did get embedded macro to work.

Answer (score 0):

The most common use of a function is to return a value or values. Your function does not appear to be returning any value. At the end of a function you would normally have a line of code that says what value the function will return, for example....

```
    RunImport = JulianSD - JulianED
End Function
```

A line like this would usually be inserted before the 'End Function' line. However if your intention is not to return a value, but instead you just want to run a vba macro, perhaps you need to change your function to a Sub routine...

```
Public Sub RunImport()
'code goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you want a macro to call a VBA procedure. Macros can only call Functions, not Subs. Which is why I ask in earlier comment - Why use a macro?